# Get the Mean of the elements in a matrix

Tags: python, list, sum, list-comprehension

Hello guys I'm getting familiar with Python and reached a problem
So I'm trying to get the mean of a matrix using only for loops and list comprehensions.

This is the code:

```
def vector_mean(vectors):
    """Computes the element-wise average"""

    for v in vectors: # Returns [1,2],[3,4],[5,6]
        return(sum(v[i]/len(v)) for i in range(v))
    

assert vector_mean([[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]]) == [3, 4]

vector_mean([[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]])
```

So the thing is the Sum method has a problem with iterating over the matrix(vector_mean)
and gives the following error after running it:

TypeError: 'list' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

Can anyone help me out and solve this problem with my code?
or if you can edit my code and pave it to be fixed, that will be great.

I believe the `return(sum(v[i]/len(v)) for i in range(v)) part` should gets the first number in each smaller list(1,3,5) and then sum them up to each other and divide it to the length of the v.

Comment: A couple things: you probably don't want to `return` inside your loop because that will end the loop before the second iteration. And if `v` is a vector, it's not clear what `range(v)` should do. I'm not sure if using `zip` is "allowed" for you, but that is the normal way to get columns in python — so your function could be a single line `return [sum(v)/len(v) for v in zip(*vectors)]`. Here `v` would be a column vector.

Comment: You are using Python List of Lists not a matrix in the row/column sense. You should look into the Numpy module which makes such operations easier (and much faster for large data sets).

Comment: @Mark Hey Mark, Thanks for replay, v is actually an iterable element such 'i' in loops, which at the result of iterating over vectors, v will be [1,2] then [3,4] and etc; in here I'm planing to sum all the first values i.e (1,3,5) and get the their average and doing same for the second values in each smaller list so the result should be [3,4] after the completion of the code.

Comment: If `v` is an iterable, you don't want `for i in range(v)` because `range()` expects a number like `range(5)` which will iterate from 0 to 4. You probably just want `for i in v`, which will assign each element to  `i` in turn.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below I have made a modification to your attempt. In the `vector_mean` function I calculate the mean for one element of each sublist at a time. So for this example I first create `[1,3,5]` then calculate the mean `3` and in the next `for` loop I create `[2,4,6]` and calculate the mean `4`.

```
def vector_mean(vectors):
    """Computes the element-wise average"""
    nr_elements = len(vectors[0])
    mean_vec = []
    for i in range(nr_elements):
        mean_vec.append(sum([
            vec[i] for vec in vectors
        ]) / len(vectors))
    return mean_vec
    

assert vector_mean([[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]]) == [3, 4]

vector_mean([[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]])
```

Comment: Thanks! I just ran this code, It works but I have to analyze it carefully; Thanks for you time Erik!